# Hide UI element (trigger action) when BroadcastReceiver onReceive is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I want to hide a UI element from my main activity when `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver` is called.

BroadcastReceiver:

**Manifest**

```
receiver android:name=".ProcessTimerReceiver"
```

**Code**

```
public class ProcessTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
           // call function
        }
    }
}
```

On a button click:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProcessTimerReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.setAction(ProcessTimerReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),
    REQUEST_CODE_ALARM, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

It has to run when the app is closed.

When the onReceive action is called, I want to hide a UI element from a Fragment (if the app is running), but I don't know how to reach the Fragments' elements from the BroadcastReceiver.

Please help me. Thanks!

**UPDATE1:**

**ProcessTimerReceiver**

```
public class ProcessTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Helper helper;

    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private Vibrator v;
    private long[] pattern_normal = {100, 300, 100, 300, 100, 300};

    public static final String ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER = "ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER";

    private static final int MUTE_NOW_NORMAL_AT = 0;
    private static final int NORMAL_NOW_MUTE_AT = 1;
    private static final int MUTE_NOW_NORMAL_IN = 2;
    private static final int NORMAL_NOW_MUTE_IN = 3;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                helper = new Helper(context);

                audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);


                switch (helper.getTimerMode()){
                    case -1:
                    helper.logD("Error while setting timer! (getTimerMode = -1)");
                        break;
                    case MUTE_NOW_NORMAL_AT:
                    helper.logD("MUTE_NOW_NORMAL_AT" + " RingerMode: " + audioManager.getRingerMode());

                            helper.setToTimerNormalMode();

                        break;
                    case NORMAL_NOW_MUTE_AT:
                    helper.logD("NORMAL_NOW_MUTE_AT" + " RingerMode: " + audioManager.getRingerMode());

                            helper.setToTimerVibrateMode();

                        break;
                    case MUTE_NOW_NORMAL_IN:
                    helper.logD("MUTE_NOW_NORMAL_IN" + " RingerMode: " + audioManager.getRingerMode());

                            helper.setToTimerNormalMode();

                        break;
                    case NORMAL_NOW_MUTE_IN:
                        helper.logD("NORMAL_NOW_MUTE_IN" + " RingerMode: " + audioManager.getRingerMode());

                            helper.setToTimerVibrateMode();

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Important functions what use this receiver:

**TimerTabbedActivity**

```
public class TimerTabbedActivity extends Fragment {
  private int REQUEST_CODE_ALARM = 1001;
  private ConstraintLayout clAdvanced;
  //...

   private void createAlarm() {
       Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProcessTimerReceiver.class);
       alarmIntent.setAction(ProcessTimerReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_ALARM, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       //...
   }

    public void cancelAlarm() {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProcessTimerReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction(ProcessTimerReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_ALARM, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //...
    }

    private boolean checkForAlarm() {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProcessTimerReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction(ProcessTimerReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER);
        boolean bIsAlarmWorking = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_ALARM, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
        helper.logD("Alarm is" + (bIsAlarmWorking ? "" : " NOT") + " working");
        return bIsAlarmWorking;
    }

}
```

So because of these functions, and mainly because of the use of the PendingIntent I'm not sure how to register programatically the receiver, and how to rewrite these functions - and also not sure how to register it if the receiver is defined in its' separate class (separate .java file).

**And I want to hide clAdvanced ConstraintLayout when the onReceive is called from the ProcessTimerReceiver.**

**UPDATE2:**

I try to do this in the following way, but it's still not working:

```
public class ProcessTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private OnReceiveListener onReceiveListener = null;

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if(onReceiveListener != null) {
                onReceiveListener.onReceive(intent);
                helper.logD("onReceiveListener != null");
            }
            else {
                helper.logD("onReceiveListener == null");
            }

            if (ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}


public class TimerTabbedActivity extends Fragment implements ProcessTimerReceiver.OnReceiveListener {

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final String ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER = "ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER";
        ProcessTimerReceiver processTimerReceiver = new ProcessTimerReceiver();
        processTimerReceiver.setOnReceiveListener(this);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(processTimerReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Intent intent) {
        helper.logD("in onReceive");
        clTimerInformation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Now it says,

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void logD(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

What do I do wrong?

***What I want to achieve: if the timer expires, hide the layout (if the app is running).***

Comment: Register the fragment programatically in fragment and define one interface listener for callbacks.

Comment: I'm going to update the question with my codes. Please help me modify it. Whenever I try to modify it in this way (as you suggested), something is missing.

Comment: @nomag Could you please check what's wrong here? I followed your advice, but I may miss something. Thanks.